# How center the value 0[threshold], the line which separates positive and negative value?

Tags: highcharts

In the below demo link, if user clicks on series or legend [Jane or John] the values or graph dynamic sets the y axis values based on the series input.

Is there a way to set a static or equal set of values on either side of threshold? [7.5,5,2.5,0-2.5,-5,-7.5]??? which remains constant?

[Example from highcharts demo section](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-negative/)

```
series: [{
            name: 'John',
            data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
        }, {
            name: 'Jane',
            data: [2, -2, -3, 2, 1]
        }, {
            name: 'Joe',
            data: [3, 4, 4, -2, 5]
        }]
```

Comment: Possible answer: [Highcharts - Keep Zero Centered on Y-Axis with Negative Values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17087704/highcharts-keep-zero-centered-on-y-axis-with-negative-values)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set min/max values on the Y-axis, like bellow

```
    yAxis: {
        min: -7.5,
        max: 7.5
    }
```

Or you can do let highcharts set the extremes, but set manually after

```
var chart = $('#container').highcharts({
   ...
}).highcharts();
var extremes = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
chart.yAxis[0].setExtremes(extremes.min, extremes.max);
```

Comment: This works but only the MAX and MIN value will be added correctly. But if I give minorTickInterval: 'auto' I don't see any values I just see 0 & max value and no ticks in between.

Comment: Please make a fiddle that illustrate your problem.

Comment: Whats wrong in this fiddle where `minorTickInterval` is used? http://jsfiddle.net/GSjCw/