# Highcharts - Keep Zero Centered on Y-Axis with Negative Values

Tags: highcharts

I have an area chart with negative values.  Nothing insanely different from [the example they give](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/area-negative), but there's one twist: I'd like to keep zero centered on the Y axis.

I know this can be achieved by setting the `yAxis.max` to some value *n* and `yAxis.min` to *−n*, with *n* representing the absolute value of either the peak of the chart or the trough, whichever is larger (as in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j3NTM/)).  However, my data is dynamic, so I don't know ahead of time what *n* needs to be.

I'm relatively new to Highcharts, so it's possible I'm missing a way to do this through configuration and let Highcharts take care of it for me, but it's looking like I'll need to use Javascript to manually adjust the y axis myself when the page loads, and as new data comes in.

Is there an easy, configuration-driven way to keep zero centered on the Y axis?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I ended up finding a way to do this through configuration after digging even further into the Highcharts API.  Each axis has a configuration option called `tickPositioner` for which you provide a function which returns an array.  This array contains the exact values where you want ticks to appear on the axis.  Here is my new `tickPositioner` configuration, which places five ticks on my Y axis, with zero neatly in the middle and the max at both extremes :

```
yAxis: {

    tickPositioner: function () {

        var maxDeviation = Math.ceil(Math.max(Math.abs(this.dataMax), Math.abs(this.dataMin)));
        var halfMaxDeviation = Math.ceil(maxDeviation / 2);

        return [-maxDeviation, -halfMaxDeviation, 0, halfMaxDeviation, maxDeviation];
    },

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old post, but thought I would post my solution anyway (which is inspired from the one macserv suggested above in the accepted answer) as it may help others who are looking for a similar solution:

```
tickPositioner: function (min, max) {
            var maxDeviation = Math.ceil(Math.max(Math.abs(this.dataMax), Math.abs(this.dataMin)));
            return this.getLinearTickPositions(this.tickInterval, -maxDeviation, maxDeviation);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with the getExtremes and setExtremes methods

- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes%28%29
- http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes%28%29

example:

http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/j3NTM/1/

```
var ext = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.  I did find and try these methods, but in my question, I was looking for a way to do this through chart configuration without manipulating it externally.  I did find an answer; see below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. The nice thing about this is that you can maintain the `tickInterval`.

```
  tickPositioner(min, max) {
    let { tickPositions, tickInterval } = this;
    tickPositions = _.map(tickPositions, (tickPos) => Math.abs(tickPos));
    tickPositions = tickPositions.sort((a, b) => (b - a));

    const maxTickPosition = _.first(tickPositions);
    let minTickPosition = maxTickPosition * -1;

    let newTickPositions = [];
    while (minTickPosition <= maxTickPosition) {
      newTickPositions.push(minTickPosition);
      minTickPosition += tickInterval;
    }

    return newTickPositions;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case someone is searching,

One option more. I ended up in a similar situation. Follows my solution:

```
tickPositioner: function () {
    var dataMin,
    dataMax = this.dataMax;
    var positivePositions = [], negativePositions = [];

    if(this.dataMin<0) dataMin = this.dataMin*-1;
    if(this.dataMax<0) dataMax = this.dataMax*-1;

    for (var i = 0; i <= (dataMin)+10; i+=10) {
        negativePositions.push(i*-1)
    }

    negativePositions.reverse().pop();

    for (var i = 0; i <= (dataMax)+10; i+=10) {
        positivePositions.push(i)
    }

    return negativePositions.concat(positivePositions);

},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/j3NTM/21/

Comment: it doesnt look like it's centered

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question but recently I have had the same problem, and here is my solution which might be generalized:

```js
const TICK_PRECISION = 2;
const AXIS_MAX_EXPAND_RATE = 1.2;

function setAxisTicks(axis, tickCount) {
    // first you calc the max from the data, then multiply with 1.1 or 1.2 
    // which can expand the max a little, in order to leave some space from the bottom/top to the max value. 
    // toPrecision decide the significant number.
    let maxDeviation = (Math.max(Math.abs(axis.dataMax), Math.abs(axis.dataMin)) * AXIS_MAX_EXPAND_RATE).toPrecision(TICK_PRECISION);

    // in case it is not a whole number
    let wholeMaxDeviation = maxDeviation * 10 ** TICK_PRECISION;

    // halfCount will be the tick counts on each side of 0
    let halfCount = Math.floor(tickCount / 2);

    // look for the nearest larger number which can mod the halfCount
    while (wholeMaxDeviation % halfCount != 0) {
        wholeMaxDeviation++;
    }

    // calc the unit tick amount, remember to divide by the precision
    let unitTick = (wholeMaxDeviation / halfCount) / 10 ** TICK_PRECISION;

    // finally get all ticks
    let tickPositions = [];
    for (let i = -halfCount; i <= halfCount; i++) {
        // there are problems with the precision when multiply a float, make sure no anything like 1.6666666667 in your result
        let tick = parseFloat((unitTick * i).toFixed(TICK_PRECISION));
        tickPositions.push(tick);
    }
    return tickPositions;
}
```

So in your chart axis tickPositioner you may add :

```js
tickPositioner: function () {
    return setAxisTicks(this, 7);
},
```